# PHP echo uploaded image content

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I'm trying to echo an image content from an uploaded file with this code:

```
<?php
$imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $imgContent;
?>
```

But it just shows an small empty square. I must upload and fetch a BLOB field from mysql to show on the browser, but it's not saving correctly.

Comment: why addslashes??

Comment: If you `addslashes()` you will likely corrupt the image file encoding

Comment: And you dont make any checks that the uploaded image is in fact a `.png` before doing `header("Content-type: image/png");`

Comment: May be useful to see the code you used to save the images to the database. In case you corrupted the file there before saving it

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Lars Stegelitz and RiggsFolly, I corrupted the file by adding `addslashes` on the file content. By removing it I could see the image being returned back.

I wroted that simple script just to test if I getting the image content correctly. In the real code I'm checking the file type.